How can I build ROS 2 as a variant?
According to REP 2001, ROS 2 comes in 6 variants.

ROS Core
ROS Base
Desktop
Perception
Simulation
Desktop Full

Additionally, there are 2 variants for development, referred to as ROS infrastructure.

ROS Build Essential
ROS Dev Tools

I can see how the development variants can be built because they are less complex as per the ROS infrastructure repository, ros-infrastructure/infra-variants.
However, I can't seem to figure out how ROS end user variants are packaged.
The ROS Variants repository, ros2/variants has the ament packages for each variant.
From the build from source instructions for Ubuntu, we use vcs import to get all the repositories, rosdep install to install them.
But then how can I choose to build just one of the variants? And how do I package it? I think bloom is used for that purpose, but I wasn't able to find any reference to its use anywhere, including GitHub Actions.
Also, what is the variant of the default source build?
